# Convert easting and northing to degrees north and west

Tags: utm, degrees-minutes-seconds

I need to convert:

Easting 2451890.770 
Northing 7438891.286

The location is in Dumfries, New Brunswick. I’m assuming it’s UTM from other search results I’ve seen. I have NO idea what to do

To degrees north and degrees west. How? Am I missing some piece of info?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What software or language? Have you been thinking that your coordinates are just numbers if you do not know in which coordinate system they are and thus conversion is practically impossible.

Comment: Please edit question and include where this point is on the earth (city, county).

Comment: You will need to know what coordinate system is being used.  It is probably UTM, but if so you will still need to specify the UTM zone (or at least the location, so that the zone can be determined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These coordinates might be in New Brunswick Stereographic. Check your Easting coordinate, I think there is a missing digit. Using X=2451890.770 and Y=7438891.286 I arrive at N45° 56' 54.620", W67° 07' 13.896" in Dumfries.

[This online converter](http://webapp.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/geod/tools-outils/trx.php) can help you convert your coordinates from UTM/MTM/Stereo to Latitude/Longitude

Comment: Did you do your conversion as NB Stereographic, or some other means?

Comment: You were correct at the missing digit. Holy cow, how did you get the correct one?

Comment: I had to select NB-NAD83(CSRS) as the zone, and 0.000 for h

Comment: Yes, that's the one to use : NB-NAD83(CSRS), it is a stereographic double projection, unlike most other coordinate systems in Canada which use UTM or MTM.

Comment: Yeah, I used a bit of deduction here, the only digit that made sense was a 4 there, and the Northing matched well, so I thought it must be that projection.

Comment: Now I just wish my cell phone compass was more accurate!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which coordinate system is being used.  It is probabably UTM, based on the tag in your question.  If so, you will need to figure out which UTM zone the location is in.

You can lookup which UTM zone the location is is using a variety of resources including online references such as [this one](http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm).

Once you have this information, there are many online converters you can use.  Just [Google 'UTM coordinate converter'](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=utm%20coordinate%20converter&rlz=1C1EJFA_enAU783AU783&oq=UTM%20coordinate%20converter&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.9010j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

(If the coordinate system is NOT UTM, then you will need to find a coordinate converter for which ever system it is.  Or use a GIS to create a feature with those coordinates in their native projected coordinate system, project the feature to a geographic coordinate system and then check it's new coordinates.)